# Better way of mapping _POST parameters to variables

Tags: php, post, dry, url-parameters

I am sure that there is a better way of mapping all the _POST parameters to variables with the same name. Does anybody know how to do this better?

```
$ownerName = $_POST["ownerName"];
$ownerEmail = $_POST["ownerEmail"];
$ownerPhone = $_POST["ownerPhone"];
$ownerAddress = $_POST["ownerAddress"];
$buyerName = $_POST["buyerName"];
$buyerEmail = $_POST["buyerEmail"];
$buyerPhone = $_POST["buyerPhone"];
$buyerAddress = $_POST["buyerAddress"];
$propertyAddress = $_POST["propertyAddress"];
$parcelNumber = $_POST["parcelNumber"];
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a function in PHP to [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) the values to vars:

```
<?php
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
?>
```

Comment: Wow I learned something new today. Curious how secure this really is? For example, if I have a boolean '$authorized' and someone posts with `authorized=true` would it overwrite that value.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the perfect answer, and for helping the n00b. =D

Comment: @Amir with the second parameter you can avoid that.. the one I put "EXTR_SKIP" will do exactly that.. if the var already exists, don't override.

Comment: Amir, that's what the EXTR_SKIP is for, if the variable already exists, it will not overwrite it.

Comment: Amir - I think that it would just set the variable `$authorized` to a value of `true`. Isn't that right, SeRPRo?

Comment: @Crossdiver the second parameter is the one that sets the behaviour.

Comment: @CRossdriver: it'd set a STRING `true`, never a boolean true. Everything in POST/GET/REQUEST/COOKIE is a string.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar you're welcome. Crossdiver you can mark the answered if you think is correct :)

Comment: @SeRPRo - Ahh, I see.
MarcB - Gotcha, url params are always strings. Very good to know.
SeRPRo - yep, just waiting for the countdown. 5mins left. =D

Comment: Its a very cool function but it says on the page, WARNING - Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET, $_FILES, etc.). If you do, for example if you want to run old code that relies on register_globals temporarily, make sure you use one of the non-overwriting extract_type values such as EXTR_SKIP and be aware that you should extract in the same order that's defined in variables_order within the php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a foreach this way (differently from `extract` you can manipulate/check the variable name or the values

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) 
   $$key = $value;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on php > 5, I would recommend taking a look at this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

The filter input functions allow you to easily apply some validation and sanitation, which you will probably want.